# Saving chess board to text file delphi

Tags: delphi

have attempted to save this chess board to a text file and have encountered this error.

Just for some clarity the board variable:

```
Const BoardDimension = 8;

Type
  TBoard = Array[1..BoardDimension, 1..BoardDimension] Of String;

Procedure SaveBoard(Var Board : TBoard);
var
  fptr:text;
  i,j:integer;
  save:char;
begin
  Write('Do you want a save a game? (Enter Y for yes)');
  Readln(save);
  If (Ord(save) >= 97) and (Ord(save) <= 122)
  Then save := Chr(Ord(save) - 32);
  if save='Y'
  then
    begin
      assign(fptr,'SBoard.txt');
      rewrite(fptr);
      reset(fptr);

      for i := 1 to 8 do
      begin
        for j := 1 to 8 do
          begin
            if j=8 then
              writeln(fptr,Board[i,j])
            else
              begin
                write(fptr,Board[i,j]);
                write(fptr,',')
              end
          end;
      end;
      close(fptr);
    end;
end;
```

A screen grab of the error. Also a screen grab of the line the error was triggered.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I/O error [105](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.IOResult) is "file not open for output". That is because this code is wrong:

```
rewrite(fptr);
reset(fptr);
```

The call to `reset` makes the file read-only. Simply remove it since it serves no purpose. The call to `rewrite` creates the new file and opens it for writing.

Comment: Deleted my duplicate answer as I was seconds too slow. This was because I had to refresh my memory. @Aleem have a look at the Stream classes.